# Unit test case for camunda related services

Tags: java, unit-testing, camunda

```
public variableInstance getVariableInstance(String proccessInstanceId, ProcessEngine processEngine) {
  RuntimeService runtimeService
    = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
  return runtimeService.createVariableInstanceQuery().processInstanceIdIn(processInstanceId).variableName(BiConstant.ID).singleResult();
}
```

Need help to write unit test case of this piece of code.New to unit testing.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at these documentation links and examples:

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert/blob/master/docs/User_Guide_BPMN.md
esp.
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert/blob/master/docs/User_Guide_BPMN.md#helpers-variables

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/user-guide/testing/#camunda-assertions

https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/master/snippets/rest-service-task-spring/src/test/java/org/camunda/test/RestCallExampleTest.java

```
ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService()
        .startProcessInstanceByKey("NewProductApprovalProcess", withVariables(
                "productDepartment", "Seafood",
                "rejected", false));
assertThat(pi)
        .isWaitingAt("CompleteOrUpdateProductDetailsTask")
        .task().hasCandidateGroup("Seafood").isNotAssigned();

taskService().claim(task().getId(), "Gladstone");
assertThat(task()).isAssignedTo("Gladstone");

complete(task(), withVariables("rejected", false));
assertThat(pi).variables().containsEntry("assignee","Gladstone");
```

Comment: Your code examples is not a unit test but a Process Test.